# Как посчитать количество дат в массиве?

Tags: php

Есть массив (результат вывода var_dump):

```
array(50) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-21" } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-22" } 
[2]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-22" } 
[3]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-23" } 
[4]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-23" } 
[5]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-23" } 
[6]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-24" } 
[7]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-24" } 
[8]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-25" } 
[9]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-25" } 
[10]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-26" } 
[11]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-26" } 
[12]=> array(1) { ["x"]=> string(10) "2017-09-27" }  
}
```

Пробовал через array_count_values посчитать сколько всего значений определенной даты в массиве.
Т.е за 21 число -1 , за 22 - 2 и так далее..
Все попытки спотыкаются на ошибке array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values

Как перевести значения даты в массиве в тип, который поймет array_count_values и в итоге решить задачу?

Comment: Во-первых, наверняка эти данные из БД. так может их там сразу и считать? Во-вторых, для подсчета воспользуйся [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php)

Comment: Да из mysql, но там тащатся и другие данные, которые нужны. Потом из первого массива выделяется массив только с датами

Comment: ну попробуй array_reduce

Comment: `array_count_values(array_column($input, 'x'))`

Comment: Молоток!  То, что нужно array_count_values(array_column($input, 'x'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если массив не слишком велик чтобы беспокоиться о размере выделяемой памяти под временный массив между вызовами штатных функций, то простой и компактный вариант решения:

```
$result = array_count_values(array_column($input, 'x'))
```

Для более объёмных вещей (или для поддержки музейный версий PHP, array_column появился лишь с версии 5.5) возможно сделать вычисление за один проход по исходному массиву с использованием памяти только под результирующий список:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($input as $row) {
    if (! isset($result[ $row['x'] ])) {
        $result[ $row['x'] ] = 0;
    }
    ++$result[ $row['x'] ];
}
```